# Is it possible to cast an array of one type to an array of another type whose size is different?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

For example, can I take

```
int array[12];
```

and cast it to a `char[48]` simply by casting the pointer, and given the assumption that `int` is 4 bytes on my machine? What would be the proper syntax for this, and would it apply generally?

I understand that the size of the new array wouldn't be explicit, *i.e.* I'd have to do the division myself, again, knowing that on my machine `int` is 4 bytes.

Comment: I wanted to serialize an integer array to a string (or c-string) without using any library like boost::serialization. It's for a coding exercise. I know I can do it the "naive" way, but wondered about this.

Comment: Casting pointers may or may not cause any problems. That doesn't indicate anything about whether there will be problems downstream. That depends on how you use the pointers

Comment: Do you really want to cast `int array[12]` (48 bytes on your platform) to `char array[3]` (3 bytes)? Or did you mix up the array bounds?

Comment: @IInspectable - I just did the math backwards in my example. Correcting, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper C++ way is with [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) :

```
int array[12];
char* pChar = reinterpret_cast<char*>(array);
```

You should note that `sizeof(array)` will be `12*sizeof(int)` which is equal to `12 * (sizeof(int) / sizeof(char))`, which in most (if not any) machine is larger than `sizeof(char[3])` since sizeof(char) is usually a quarter of `sizeof(int)`.

So `int array[12];` can be interpeted as `char array[12*4];`

Comment: An `int` is larger than a `char` on **any** platform (`int` is at least 16 bits wide).

Answer (score 1):

You can cast most pointer types to most other pointer types using [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

Usage to : `auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(array);`.

Rather than rely on the fact that `int` is 4 bytes on your system, you can use `sizeof(int)` as a constant instead. The wording of your question makes it seem like you may be confused about the "size" of the array when cast to `char*`. `int` is `sizeof(int)` times larger than `char`. If `sizeof(int) == 4` then your `int`s take up `4 * 12 = 48` bytes in your array, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int array[12];
 char * p = (char *) array;
 // do what you want with p
```

Of course, `p` doesn't have the type `char[3]`, but this probably doesn't matter to you.